# Bootstrap 4 menu not opening other dropdowns

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Because I am trying to get the Text to remain a link and the dropdown toggle to open the dropdown, which, I've managed to achieve. But it causing Dropdown-2 to toggle/open Dropdown-1. And only Dropdown-1 is working.

Basically, can't figure out why its only opening Dropdown-1 only which ever Dropdown I click

I'm using Bootstrap 4.4.1

You can see the Pen here https://codepen.io/cr8tivly/pen/MWavBJr

This is the markup

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light"> 
  <ul class="row row-cols-4 navbar-nav main relative list-unstyled col-6"> 
    <li class="col nav-item dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
      <a class="" href="http://google.com">Dropdown-1</a> 
      <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
        <li>item-1-one</li> 
        <li>item-2-one</li> 
        <li>item-3-one</li> 
        <li>item-4-one</li> 
      </ul> 
    </li> 
    <li class="col nav-item dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
      <a class="" href="http://google.com">Dropdown-2</a> 
      <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
        <li>item-1-two</li> 
        <li>item-2-two</li> 
        <li>item-3-two</li> 
        <li>item-4-two</li> 
      </ul> 
    </li> 
    <li class="col"><a href="#">Three</a></li> 
    <li class="col"><a href="#">Four</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `data-toggle="dropdown"` should be on the `a`. Check the [documentation here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).

Instead of:

```
<li class="col nav-item dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
  <a>Dropdown-1</a>
```

Use:

```
<li class="col nav-item dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
  <a data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown-1</a>
```

Updated [pen here](https://codepen.io/bortao/pen/PoPKBXW).

Comment: Yes, I intentionally did it lthat way because,I want the + to expand the dropdown and the Text to remain a link

Answer (score 0):

If you want the plus sign to open the dropdown and the text to open a link you can do this:

```
<li class="col nav-item">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <a class="btn btn-link" href="http://google.com">Dropdown-2</a> 
    <button class="btn btn-light dropdown" id="d2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">+</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="d2"> 
     <li>item-1-two</li> 
     <li>item-2-two</li>
     <li>item-3-two</li> 
     <li>item-4-two</li> 
    </ul>
  </div> 
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the solution you've described, however, because the menu is generated from a CMS, I don't have access to the entire markup, kinda have to work with what I have shared above

Comment: Ok. Then I guess you can manually listen for click event in the li element and add the class "show" to the dropdown-menu to display it.

Comment: I suppose that's one way to approach. will give it a shot. Thanks